# How to update runtimeStatus for Azure Durable Function?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-durable-functions

I can manually update the runtimeStatus by going into the azure storage explorer. Storage Explorer -> Tables -> HubNameInstances -> edit entity

But is there an easy way to do this in code?

Comment: Your question is too inspecific. Would be easier if you provide a small, self-contained example of what your Function is doing. The example you are showing has the issue, that it contains static conditionals, which do [not work the way you expect](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/durable/durable-functions-code-constraints#orchestrator-code-constraints) for a _Durable_ Azure Function.

Comment: Seems to me you'd be better off spending your time understanding what makes this "get stuck" as this shouldn't happen

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

IF you want to **edit**/**update** the Durable function Entity

An operation executes, it might update the internal state of the entity. It might also call external services and wait for a response. Entities communicate with other entities, orchestrations, and clients by using messages that are implicitly sent via reliable queues.

A simple `Counter` entity implemented as a durable function. This function defines three operations, `add`, `reset`, and `get`, each of which operates on an integer state.

```
[FunctionName("QueryCounter")]
public static async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Run(
[HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function)] HttpRequestMessage req,
[DurableClient] IDurableEntityClient client)
{
    var entityId = new EntityId(nameof(Counter), "myCounter");
    EntityStateResponse<JObject> stateResponse = await client.ReadEntityStateAsync<JObject>(entityId);
    return req.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, stateResponse.EntityState);
}
```

**Note**

> Calling an entity from an orchestrator function is similar to calling
> an [**activity function**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/durable/durable-functions-types-features-overview#activity-functions) from an orchestrator function. The main difference is that entity functions are durable objects with an address, which is the entity ID. Entity functions support specifying an operation name. Activity functions, on the other hand, are stateless and don't have the concept of operations.

Refer [doc for concept](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/durable/durable-functions-entities?tabs=csharp) &  [doc for steps to implement in code](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/durable/durable-functions-dotnet-entities)